# How to access data from a Roomdatabase inside a BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-room, android-livedata

I need to access data from my Room database inside a BroadCastReceiver class, but as you know we need a lifecycle owner to get an instance of ViewModel class as shown below.

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationHelper.sendFinanceLoggingNotification(context);
        RecurrenceInfoViewModel recurrenceInfoViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RecurrenceInfoViewModel.class);

    }
}
```

when passing "this" as the lifecycle owner android studio is throwing error. Can anyone please guide me from where I can get a lifecycle owner inside a BroadCastReceiver or if you can suggest any other way of accessing the data. Below are my ViewModel and Repository classes

```
    public class RecurrenceInfoViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {


    private LiveData<List<RecurrenceInfoEntity>> allRecurrenceInfos;
    private RecurrenceInfoRepository recurrenceInfoRepository;

    public RecurrenceInfoViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        recurrenceInfoRepository=new RecurrenceInfoRepository(application);


    }

    public void insertRecurrenceInfo(RecurrenceInfoEntity recurrenceInfoEntity) {
        recurrenceInfoRepository.insertRecurrenceInfo(recurrenceInfoEntity);
    }

    public void updateRecurrenceInfo(RecurrenceInfoEntity recurrenceInfoEntity) {

        recurrenceInfoRepository.updateRecurrenceInfo(recurrenceInfoEntity);
    }

    public void deleteRecurrenceInfo(RecurrenceInfoEntity recurrenceInfoEntity) {
        recurrenceInfoRepository.deleteRecurrenceInfo(recurrenceInfoEntity);
    }

    public void deleteAllRecurrenceInfos() {
        recurrenceInfoRepository.deleteAllRecurrenceInfo();
    }



    public LiveData<RecurrenceInfoEntity> getAllRecurrenceInfos(String recurrenceInfoKey) {
        return recurrenceInfoRepository.getRecurrenceInfoEntityList(recurrenceInfoKey);
    }
}





public class RecurrenceInfoRepository {


    private RecurrenceInfoDao recurrenceInfoEntityDao;
    private LiveData<List<RecurrenceInfoEntity>> recurrenceInfoEntityList;

    public RecurrenceInfoRepository(Context context) {

        MoneyManagerDatabase moneyManagerDatabase = MoneyManagerDatabase.getInstance(context);
        recurrenceInfoEntityDao = moneyManagerDatabase.getRecurrenceInfoDao();
        recurrenceInfoEntityList = recurrenceInfoEntityDao.getAllRecurrenceInfo();


    }

    public void insertRecurrenceInfo(RecurrenceInfoEntity data) {

        new PerformSingleColumnDataOperations(recurrenceInfoEntityDao,
                Constants.INSERT_SINGLE_NODE_DATABASE_OPERATION).execute(data);
    }

    public void updateRecurrenceInfo(RecurrenceInfoEntity data) {
        new PerformSingleColumnDataOperations(recurrenceInfoEntityDao,
                Constants.UPDATE_SINGLE_NODE_DATABASE_OPERATION).execute(data);
    }

    public void deleteRecurrenceInfo(RecurrenceInfoEntity data) {
        new PerformSingleColumnDataOperations(recurrenceInfoEntityDao,
                Constants.DELETE_SINGLE_NODE_DATABASE_OPERATION).execute(data);
    }

    public void deleteRecurrenceInfo(String  type) {
        new PerformSingleColumnDataOperations(recurrenceInfoEntityDao,
                Constants.DELETE_SINGLE_NODE_DATABASE_OPERATION).execute();
    }

    public void deleteAllRecurrenceInfo() {
        new PerformSingleColumnDataOperations(recurrenceInfoEntityDao,
                Constants.DELETE_ALL_NODES_DATABASE_OPERATION).execute();
    }

    public LiveData<RecurrenceInfoEntity> getRecurrenceInfoEntityList(String key) {
        return recurrenceInfoEntityDao.getAllRecurrenceInfo(key);
    }


    private static class PerformSingleColumnDataOperations extends AsyncTask<RecurrenceInfoEntity, Void, Void> {

        private RecurrenceInfoDao dataDao;
        private String operationType;


        PerformSingleColumnDataOperations(RecurrenceInfoDao dataDao, String operationType) {
            this.dataDao = dataDao;
            this.operationType = operationType;

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(RecurrenceInfoEntity... recurrenceInfoEntities) {
            switch (operationType) {
                case Constants.INSERT_SINGLE_NODE_DATABASE_OPERATION:
                    dataDao.insertRecurrenceInfo(recurrenceInfoEntities[0]);
                    break;
                case Constants.UPDATE_SINGLE_NODE_DATABASE_OPERATION:
                    dataDao.updateRecurrenceInfo(recurrenceInfoEntities[0]);
                    break;
                case Constants.DELETE_SINGLE_NODE_DATABASE_OPERATION:
                    dataDao.deleteRecurrenceInfo(recurrenceInfoEntities[0]);
                    break;
                case Constants.DELETE_ALL_NODES_DATABASE_OPERATION:
                    dataDao.deleteAllRecurrenceInfo();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }




}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend that you delegate the work to a `WorkManager` or `JobIntentService`.

Comment: CommonsWare I am doing this because I need to repeatedly generate and schedule Notifications on user choice. When a Notification is generated and onReceive is called I schedule the next Notification by fetching the data from the database and deciding the time of next Notification using that data.  Will I be able to achieve the same using  "WorkManager" or "JobIntentService"? and Aside from this question, I am a big fan of your books Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: "Will I be able to achieve the same using "WorkManager" or "JobIntentService"?" -- yes. The problems with a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` is that it does not live very long and `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread. Doing database I/O is risky and may freeze your app's UI (if it happens to be in the foreground at that time). Delegating the work to a `Worker` (with `WorkManager`) or `JobIntentService` gives you more time to do the work and a background thread on which to do it. And thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above problem by NOT using LiveData.
You can access data from Room anywhere by just providing the ApplicationContext as shown below.

DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM reference_info where recurrenceInfoPrimaryKey=:recurrenceinfoprimkey")
    RecurrenceInfoEntity getAllRecurrenceInfoWithOutLiveData(String recurrenceinfoprimkey);
```

Repository:

```
  public RecurrenceInfoEntity getRecurrenceInfoEntityWithOutLiveData(String key) {
        return recurrenceInfoEntityDao.getAllRecurrenceInfoWithOutLiveData(key);
    }
```

BroadCastReceiver:

```
    public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
new Thread(() -> {          
      RecurrenceInfoEntity recurrenceInfoEntity = 
     recurrenceInfoRepository.getRecurrenceInfoEntityWithOutLiveData(Constants.LOG_FINANCES_RECURRENCE_KEY);

         }).start();
        }
```